# InAppBrowser does not go back to the previous state of my app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am using [InAppBrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) in my app to open a link in the system browser. It is working fine. But, when i close the browser using the backbutton, i could not go to my previous state of the app. I need to simply close the browser and return to previous state of my app.

```
// in .html file
  <ion-col col-4>
       <a href= "#" ion-item class="min-height"
            (click)="GotoLink(patientNote[0].FileUrl)">
            <ion-icon name="ios-attach-outline" class="note-icon"></ion-icon>
       </a>
  </ion-col>

// in .ts file
    import {InAppBrowser} from "@ionic-native/in-app-browser";

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-update-progress-note',
      templateUrl: 'update-progress-note.html',
    })
    export class UpdateProgressNotePage {

    constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser){}

      private GotoLink = (url): void => {
        this.iab.create(url, '_system', 'location=yes, hardwareback=no');
      };
    }
```

How can i simply close the browser when using close button of the browser or using the back button and return to the previous step of my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to remove the **href="#"** from anchor tag. It was a very silly mistake from me.